# Incompatible return Type while narrowing double to float

Tags: java, oop, casting, type-conversion, return-type

I'm writing my own implementation of an `Vector`. I want this to be as wide as possible so I wrote it with all fields and values being `double`. Now I made a second Object `FloatVector` which extends my main Class `2DVector`. It's only job is to provide Getter-Methods of `2DVector` that are already cast my double-Values to float-Values (I know, there are other - and probably better - ways of doing that, but I really can't be bothered adding `(float) ...` to everything related with my Vectors).

Anyway, while doing the above I ran into a problem I didn't expect to happen. Looking at the code below:

```
public class Vector2D {
    double x;
    
    public double getX() { return x;}
}
```

```
public class FloatVector extends 2DVector {
    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return (float) super.getX();
    }
}
```

Eclipse throws an Error, that `The return Type is incompatible with Vector2D.getX()` and I can't really understand why this is.

I tried replacing the primitive casting to the following:

```
@Override
public Float angleBetween() {
    return Float.valueOf( (float) super.getMagnitude() );
}
```

but also to no avail.

Comment: Yes, you need to look into [what overriding is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1). You can't override a method by returning a different type

Comment: It's not about casting. You pretend to override a method which returns a `double` while you are not because your method in `FloatVector` returns a `float`.

Comment: What you're attempting would probably be better done with boxed primitives and generics

Comment: Well, I'm working with Processing and every method-Parameter it provides only accepts floats and I was getting so frustrated having to put (float) all over the place.

Comment: Let's say that we have two vectors. One stores values in the `double`, the other stores values in the `float`. What can make us say that the second vector **extands** the first? Is it possible to say that the `FloatVector` is *bigger* than `DoubleVector`? No. These two vectors do not differ in anything other than the type of values that they store. Therefore, inheritance does not work here.

Answer (score 1):

try Generic Types

```
public class Vector2D<T> {
    T x;

    public T getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

```
public class FloatVector extends Vector2D<Float> {
    @Override
    public Float getX() {
        return super.getX();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method in the subclass with the @Override annotation must have the same return type as the method in the superclass.